# How to get CMocka report in JUnit format?

Tags: c++, c, xml, unit-testing, cmocka

I am able to use cmocka and getting default results on the screen. I want to get the results for the unit test in JUnit format.

CMocka supports JUnit format by using the env variable `CMOCKA_MESSAGE_OUTPUT` or using API `cmocka_set_message_output(CM_OUTPUT_XML);`

But still no xml file gets generated. Can anyone help out in obtaining results in JUnit format?

Answer (score 8):

The most credible source is actually the `cmocka.c` source file that contains entire implementation of the framework. This file is not too large, so I will cite something from the source file version 1.0.1.

There are two conditions to generate XML output by cmocka and the third condition is needed to store output in file.

**1. XML output can be generated only if tests are called by `cmocka_run_group_tests()`**

The customizable output format can be obtained only from the test runner `cmocka_run_group_tests()` or from its full variation `cmocka_run_group_tests_name()`.

There is no other route that can lead to XML output. If a singe test is started by `run_test()` the output cannot be XML.

The summary format

```
[  PASSED  ] 0 test(s).
[  FAILED  ] 1 test(s), listed below:
```

can be generated in one of the following possible cases:

- the test is started by one of the deprecated test runners: `run_tests()`, `_run_tests()` or `run_group_tests()`, `_run_group_tests()`; in that case it is even possible to see compilation warning about usage of a deprecated function;
- the test is started by `cmocka_run_group_tests()` and the output format is `CM_OUTPUT_STDOUT`.

**2. cmocka message output should be set to `CM_OUTPUT_XML`**

The default output format can be set by calling `cmocka_set_message_output(CM_OUTPUT_XML)` before running tests. However, even if such default is set in the test source it can be overwritten by the environment variable `CMOCKA_MESSAGE_OUTPUT`. That variable has higher priority than the default set by `cmocka_set_message_output()`.

The value of `CMOCKA_MESSAGE_OUTPUT` is *case insensitive*. The variable is taken into account if it is equal to one of the following values: `stdout`, `subunit`, `tab` or `xml`.

So, if the environment variable has value `stdout` the function `mocka_set_message_output()` has no effect.

That variable can be used to force different output formats of already compiled binary:

```
CMOCKA_MESSAGE_OUTPUT=stdout ./nulltest
CMOCKA_MESSAGE_OUTPUT=subunit ./nulltest
CMOCKA_MESSAGE_OUTPUT=tap ./nulltest
CMOCKA_MESSAGE_OUTPUT=xml ./nulltest
```

Thus, if the test is started by `cmocka_run_group_tests()` but the output is not affected by `mocka_set_message_output()` it means that there is set variable `CMOCKA_MESSAGE_OUTPUT=stdout` in the shell.

**3. It should be possible to create a new file by cmocka to write its XML output directly to that file**

If both previous conditions are satisfied, it is possible to ask cmocka to write its XML output directly to a file. If the environment variable `CMOCKA_XML_FILE` is set, then cmocka will try to write XML to file with name of that variable value.

Usage example:

```
CMOCKA_XML_FILE='./out.xml' CMOCKA_MESSAGE_OUTPUT=xml ./nulltest
```

The file is written if:

- file with such name does not exist;
- such file can be created.

Thus if there are more than one test runners in one compiled binary test application, only the first runner can write its output to that file.

The output is written to the shell even if `CMOCKA_XML_FILE` is set, but the file already exists or it cannot be created.

Of course, it is possible just to redirect shell output to a file overwriting existent file or appending to existent file if such file exists.

The example bellow can be used to check different options for output. It can be built by the command

```
gcc -g nulltest.c -o nulltest -Ipath_to_cmocka_headers -Lpath_to_cmocka_library_binary -lcmocka
```

*nulltest.c*

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <setjmp.h>
#include <cmocka.h>

/* A test case that fails. */
static void null_test_failed(void **state) {
    (void) state; /* unused */
    assert_int_equal(0, 1);
}

int main(void) {
    const struct CMUnitTest tests[] = {
        cmocka_unit_test(null_test_failed),
    };
    const struct UnitTest tests_deprecated[] = {
        unit_test(null_test_failed),
    };

    cmocka_set_message_output(CM_OUTPUT_XML);

    /* group test functions that use customizable output format */
    cmocka_run_group_tests(tests, NULL, NULL);
    cmocka_run_group_tests_name("custom group name", tests, NULL, NULL);

    /* run single test with standard output */
    run_test(null_test_failed);

    /* DEPRECATED TEST RUNNER functions that can give only standard output */
    run_tests(tests_deprecated);
    _run_tests(tests_deprecated, 1);
    run_group_tests(tests_deprecated);
    _run_group_tests(tests_deprecated, 1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Orest. That answer is certainly worth the bonus. In fact, it is the best single piece of documentation and only example of cmcoka on the internet, as far as I can find. @asn am I worng?

Comment: For completeness I updated the post by usage of `cmocka_run_group_tests_name`

Answer (score 1):

The XML is printed to stdout, you need to redirect it to a file ...

Comment: Hello Andreas, thanks for the reply. I am using CMocka 1.0.1 and have added cmocka_set_message_output(CM_OUTPUT_XML); to the main() in the unit test. But the result that i see on the stdout is in the below format... 0x3 == 0x3
cmockatest.c:8: error: Failure!
[  PASSED  ] 0 test(s).
[  FAILED  ] 1 test(s), listed below:
[  FAILED  ] test

Comment: ```asn@magrathea:~/workspace/projects/cmocka/obj> CMOCKA_MESSAGE_OUTPUT=XML ./example/simple_test 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<testsuites>
  <testsuite name="tests" time="0.009" tests="1" failures="0" errors="0" skipped="0" >
    <testcase name="null_test_success" time="0.009" >
    </testcase>
  </testsuite>
</testsuites>``` Works just fine for me ..

Comment: Hmm, if @asn _is_ the author, then I am surprised that he did not mention what I found by code reading. You can set the name of a XML output file in the environment variable CMOCKA_XML_FILE - see cmocka.c, line 1913

Comment: @Mawg You are using deprecated test runner `run_tests()`, see my answer post.

Comment: cmocka-1.1.0 has improved XML output. You can now create a XML file for each group. See https://api.cmocka.org/ -> Output formats